# Hyphenpenalty inside renewcommand visible in index in generated PDF document

Tags: macros, sectioning, hyphenation

I'm trying to prevent any of my selections from having hyphenation. Why? Because having hyphenation due to line not being wide enough is bad writing style.

I'm currently using the following custom `\selection` command to do that:

```
\let\OldSection\section
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{\OldSection{\hyphenpenalty=100000#1}}
```

It works fine. However yesterday I noticed a weird thing happening with the index in the sidebar of Evince and Okular. Both show the following:

> =100000**SectionName**

for any `\section{SectionName}` in my document. How do I fix this? On the page itself I do get for example

> **2.3 SectionName**

which is displayed correctly. However, it's obvious that internally something is broken. Is there another way to do what I'm trying to? Note that I want the absence of hyphenation only for selected commands (sections in my case since all my titles fit in a single line).

Comment: normally you want to specify headings to be \raggedright if there is any chance of line breaking, in which case it won't hyphenate anyway. But either way the declaration should be in the section setup (`\@startsection` or a package such as `titlesec`) not in the main text argument of the heading. (probably your code is failing in making pdfbookmarks or other code that is expecting _text_ there).

Comment: Does adding braces, with space, help? `\hyphenpenalty=100000{ }#1` Perhaps when #1 begins with a number, it is tacked onto the penalty number.

Comment: @RobtA that would (most likely, depending on the section formatting in use) add a visible space in the typeset output.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle OK. So, don't do `{ }`. But I wonder if the underlying problem with OP request is concatenation of the numerical hyphenpenalty with a following number. If so, then some other means of breaking might be better. Or, do it an entirely different way, as suggested below.

Comment: I tried both ` ` (just space) and `{ }`. Both don't solve the issue and the latter makes my font look weird.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle My setup is in the preamble that is before `\begin{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to prohibit hyphenation in all levels of sectioning commands, you should provide the appropriate instructions in the document's preamble. For instance, you might provide the following two instructions:

```
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\raggedright}
```

As David Carlisle has already noted in a comment, the instruction `\raggedright` automatically suppresses hyphenation.

Incidentally, the instruction `\allsectionsfont` applies to *all levels* of sectioning commands, from `\part` and `\chapter` all the way to `\paragraph` and `\subparagraph`

Comment: Thanks to both of you (@DavidCarlisle too). Well explained and works like a charm.